# SP 2007/2010 Web Services: How to update a choice field that uses a non-XML character?

Tags: 2007, web-services

So, I have a Choice field in a list with a couple choices similar to the following:

- M & P: Deliverable
- M & P: Action Item

And what I am attempting to do is update these fields using the 2007/2010 web services (well, actually SPServices.js) but it's not working well. When I send the field to the server the webservice itself reads the ampersand and refuses to parse the request. I put together a quick and dirty little function that parses some of these illegal objects but I'm unsure if SP is actually interpreting the '&' back into a '&' and indeed attempts to save an item so changed fail due to invalid data.

As I am making these edits to ~1100 items, it's simply not feasible to do this by hand. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried using the encoded value? Example: `M &amp; P: Deliverable`